# How to check multiple rows with the same foreinkey and update them step by step

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I try to explain my problem.

I have a table in my DB with more than one rows with the same FK(Foreinkey) each row have columns `ID`, `GuestUserName`, `GuestUserImage`, `GuestFrame`, `Male`, `Female`, `FK_Party` and `FK_User`. All columns except `Id` and `FK_Party` have a standard value. `FK_User` is by default set to `null` (See my `Party_Guest_TBL`).
That's my default guests for a party. Now if i try as user to join this party i want check if `FK_User` value in a row still `null` and if it is update the value with the `UserId` from user.

[image: My Party_Guest_TBL]

```
var guestNumber = await _db.Party_GuestNumber_TBL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FK_Party == PartyId);
        var partyGuest = await _db.Party_Guest_TBL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FK_Party == PartyId);
        var user = await _db.User_TBL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == UserId);
        var gender = await _db.Gender_TBL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FK_User == UserId);

        if (partyGuest.FK_Party == PartyId && partyGuest.FK_User == null && partyGuest.Male == gender.Male)
        {

            partyGuest.FK_User = user.Id;
            partyGuest.GuestUserName = user.UserName;
            partyGuest.GuestImageUrl = user.ImageUrl;
            partyGuest.GuestFrame = user.Frame;

        }
```

This works fine, but my problem is that this code only checks the first row and not the other rows as well. This means that only one row can be updated at a time. But I would like to check every row step by step until every FK_User column has been updated with a UserId.

Comment: is `PartyGuest` a `User`? And is it necesary to have data duplication in `PartyGuest`? I mean, you have a `FK_User` and just can get all data from there...

Comment: @JHBonarius PartyGuest is the default user like a placeholder for real user

Comment: "But I would like to check every row step by step until every FK_User column has been updated with a UserId." Where do these UserIds come from? There's a lot of missing details in your question, making it hard to answer.

Comment: @JHBonarius yeah is hard to explane i dont want to write to much useless stuff. The UserId´s comes from the real user who want join the party.

Comment: But you need to explain, else we cannot help you. And add information in the question, not the comments. Again, you write "But I would like to check every row step by step until every FK_User column has been updated with a UserId." which would indicate many users, but in your recent comment you're talking about "the real user" as if there's one. Be clear and complete please...

Comment: @JHBonarius  this code works fine if RealUserOne join the party but if i try to join with RealUserTwo the party there just checks the the same row and not the other one where FK_User still Null.

Comment: Where does "UserId" come from?

Comment: I update my question and set a image to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

edit: thinking about this more, I think your system setup has need to be evaluated. Why does the `PartyGuests` table have many lines with `User_FK==null`? It sounds weird.

But anyhow, here's what I think is the general idea of the answer to your explicit question.

Let's say there's a (properly scaffolded) table of users that need to be added

```cs
var userIds = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
var users = await _db.User_TBL
    .Include(u => u.Gender)
    .Where(u => userIds.Contains(u.Id) &&
                u.Gender == Gender.Male)
    .AsNoTracking();
```

Now you can add them to the party (assuming there are sufficent null positions)

```cs
var nullPartyGuests = await _db.Party_Guest_TBL
    .Where(pg => pg.FK_Party == PartyId &&
                 pg.FK_User == null)
    .GetEnumerator(); // with tracking
foreach(var user in users) {
    var partyGuest = nullPartyGuests.Current;
    //your stuff
            partyGuest.FK_User = user.Id;
            partyGuest.GuestUserName = user.UserName;
            partyGuest.GuestImageUrl = user.ImageUrl;
            partyGuest.GuestFrame = user.Frame;
    // increase enumerator
    nullPartyGuests.MoveNext();
}
// then save everything to the DB.
await _db.SaveChanges();
```

note, not tested

Answer (score 0):

I sloved it by my self.

```
 var guestNumber = await _db.Party_GuestNumber_TBL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FK_Party == PartyId);
        var user = await _db.User_TBL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == UserId);
        var gender = await _db.Gender_TBL.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FK_User == UserId);

        var partyGuest = _db.Party_Guest_TBL.Where(x => x.FK_Party == PartyId && x.FK_User == null);

        var maleGuest = partyGuest.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FK_User == null && x.Male == gender.Male);
        var femaleGuest = partyGuest.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FK_User == null && x.Female == gender.Female);

        var alreadyJoined = _db.Party_Guest_TBL.Where(u => u.GuestUserName == user.UserName).SingleOrDefault();

        if (alreadyJoined != null)
        {
            return BadRequest("This User already join the party");
        }
        else if (maleGuest.Male == gender.Male)
        {
            maleGuest.FK_User = user.Id;
            maleGuest.GuestUserName = user.UserName;
            maleGuest.GuestImageUrl = user.ImageUrl;
            maleGuest.GuestFrame = user.Frame;
        }
        else if (femaleGuest.Female == gender.Female)
        {
            femaleGuest.FK_User = user.Id;
            femaleGuest.GuestUserName = user.UserName;
            femaleGuest.GuestImageUrl = user.ImageUrl;
            femaleGuest.GuestFrame = user.Frame;
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();
```

@JHBonarius thanks you help me with your code.